# Yii2 - Javascript - finding id of input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, yii, yii2

I have a problem with client validation when showing several model forms on the same page. It's like a list where the user can toggle the input forms, only the ones that are selected will be saved.

I already wrote some javascript code that removes and reinserts the name attribute on each field, but obviously the invisible fields are still being validated, resulting in the user being unable to submit the form.

I already had a look at the "whenClient" validation property in my model, but the problem there is that I don't know how to select the field that is being validated. 
If there was only one form on the page, I could easily select each input field, but with many forms the id's are like "modelname-index-attribute".
So I would need to access the field being validated with javascript or find another way to submit the form.

By the way, I also tried to remove all the hidden forms on submit, but if a visible form has errors, the form would not be submitted and the deleted fields could not be made visible. I also encountered a strange behaviour where the client validation doesn't happen when I remove and reinsert a form using javascript, but this would be a different issue.

I add form fields like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, '['.$i.']attribute')->textInput(...); ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code here of view

Comment: Post your code please.